# can't get an "awk for loop" to work, while using basename

Tags: awk, basename

I have many xyz files that I want to run through awk. I just want to create a new file with an "_s" appended, for each one. Having a little trouble getting the basename syntax correct. Here is what I have.

```
for i in *.xyz; do awk -F" " '{printf $1 $2 $3}' > $(basename $i)_s.xyz ; done
```

Comment: im not sure either, i edited it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax for writing the output of processed files to new files with `_s` added to the filename part before the extension would be:

```
for i in *.xyz; do awk -F" " '{printf $1 $2 $3}' $i > ${i%\.*}_s.xyz ; done
```

the `${i%\.*}` part takes trims the `$i` string from the last occurence of `.` to the end effectively removing the extension.

In your example you could use `${i%\.xyz}`, but that would be less universal.

Comment: Thanks, this gets it done. I still would like to get it figured out using basename. Just because I have used that before, and with other commands using the "for" loop

Comment: Why would you need to call `basename` in this example? Adding it would create `*_s.xyz` files in your current directory for `*.xyz` files in subdirectories. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the files names as 'ls *.xyz' and then rename $i.

```
for i in `ls *.xyz`; do
  mv $i $i_s
done
```